# unable to verify the first certificate - node fetch

Tags: node.js, firebase, request, google-cloud-functions, node-fetch

I try to get data from this api: https://www.meteoromania.ro/wp-json/meteoapi/v2/starea-vremii, when I implemented the function it worked but now after some time, I get the following error:

```
Error getting RoMeteo data: FetchError: request to https://www.meteoromania.ro/wp-json/meteoapi/v2/starea-vremii failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

and this is how I make the request:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

exports.getAirQualityData = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {
  const urlRoMeteo = "https://www.meteoromania.ro/wp-json/meteoapi/v2/starea-vremii";
  const settings = { method: "GET" };
    try {
      const resRoMeteo = await fetch(urlRoMeteo);
      const jsonRoMeteo = await await resRoMeteo.json();
      const dataRoMeteo = jsonRoMeteo["features"][2]["properties"];
      const tp = dataAirVisual["tp"];
      const wind = dataRoMeteo["vant"];
      const pression = dataRoMeteo["presiunetext"];
      const dataJson = {
        "air": [{
          "airTS": airTs,
          "pm25": pm25,
          "co2": co2,
          "hm": hm,
          "tp": tp,
          "wind": wind,
          "pression": pression,
        },
        ],
      };
      try {
        await admin.firestore().collection("collection").doc("Air").update(dataJson);
        return console.log("Document 2 updated!");
      } catch (error) {
        return console.log("Error writing document 2: " + error);
      }
    } catch (error1) {
      return console.log("Error getting RoMeteo data: " + error1);
    }
}
```

I've been trying for the last 2 days to solve this error but didn't succeed, any ideas on how I can fix this?